# Delay and Limit JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function and event that triggers when the mouse leaves the window. This currently triggers every time the mouse leaves.

I would like to delay this from running so we have a 10 second period when this function won't run on page load. I would also like to limit this so it only happens once when on the page.

How would I go about this?

```
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}

addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) {
    if (evt.toElement == null && evt.relatedTarget == null) {
        jQuery('.about-us-video').one().magnificPopup('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` and unbind it inside the handler so it is only ran once.

Comment: Why would you create your own `addEvent` function, that uses jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).one('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.about-us-video').magnificPopup('open');
    });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you. I initially had an issue when using the mouseleave with document so used what I could find. Thanks for showing me a better way to do this.